# HTTP caching does not work

Tags: http, caching, header

Opening same URL from browser, and the server returns below header.
Repeating again, why it always give HTTP 200, instead of 304.
Any idea?

> HTTP/1.1 200 OK Server: Cowboy Connection: keep-alive X-Powered-By:
>   Express Content-Type: text/html Cache-Control: public, max-age=600
>   Date: Sat, 07 Nov 2015 04:41:50 GMT Transfer-Encoding: chunked Via:
>   1.1 vegur

Comment: I'm not sure how your cowboy server operates, but have you tried including a `if-modified-since <old date from last-modified value>` or `if-none-match <old etag value>` header in your client when making the request?

Comment: Thank you Mike. This helps. It appears due to my server side application always returns HTTP code 200.